Input type date, differentiate between empty and invalid
I have a modal window with a form containing an optional field of type date i.e.:
<input id="myDate" type="date" />

If I pick a date, i.e.  14/05/2024, and then remove some parts (leaving the date incomplete) i.e dd/05/2024, it seems as if the blank or the incomplete date or the wrong format are treated in the same way, as if the date would be empty. ( using jQuery´s .val() The value is empty in both situations)
Is there a way, using jQuery, to treat the empty date differently from the case when it is  incomplete or in the wrong format?

Yes this is possible, if val is empty you can check for validity.badInput to check whether the input is complete empty or there is input but its "bad input" , e.g dd/05/2024


$('#submit').on('click', function(){
  $input = $('#date');
  if ($input.val() == ""){
    if ($input[0].validity.badInput) {
      console.log("INPUT NOT EMPTY BUT INVALID!!!")
    }
    else {
      console.log("INPUT COMPLETELY EMPTY")
    }
  }
  else {
    console.log("INPUT VALID: " + $input.val() ) 
  }
 });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="date" id="date">
<input type="submit" id="submit">



